# What happens when two functions are triggered to act on the same sheet at the same time?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a few functions which apply various operations to one sheet.

Function A inserts rows and then resorts the rows after insertion.

Function B replaces cells in certain rows depending on the ID key of that row (ID is just a number in column A).

Functions A and B are triggered independently by timed triggers with no guarantee that they won't be triggered at the same time.

My concern is that Function A and B run at the same time, and while B is working, A does a resort, and therefore B replaces cells in the wrong row.

How does Google handle concurrent triggers in the same project and where the functions act on the same sheet?

Comment: Unfortunately, in my experience, it seems that when 2 functions are run by the time-driven trigger, both functions cannot be run exclusively under the default. When you want to exclusively run 2 functions, how about using Lock Service? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock) By this, each function is not run, simultaneously. But I'm not sure whether this is the direction you expect. So when this is not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: About the usage of the lock service, I think that these threads might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34878161 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/43223774

Comment: Another possibility would be set only one function on time trigger and call the second function from the first function.